# Using the binomial theorem, show that $7^n +2$ is divisible by $3$

Tags: divisibility, binomial-theorem

Use binomial theorem to show that $7^n + 2$ is divisible by $3$.

What I've done:
$$\begin{aligned}
(a+b)^n &= \sum_{r=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{r}a^{n-r}b^r \\\\
7^n+2 &=( 1+6)^n+2\\
&= \sum_{r=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{r}1^{n-r}\times6^r+2 \\
&= \sum_{r=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{r}6^r+2
\end{aligned}$$

But I'm not sure what to do from there. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Your binormial formula is incorrect

Comment: Use the fact that $\binom n0r^0+2=3$.

Comment: Either use $3\mid 7\!-\!1\mid 7^n\!-1$ by the [Factor Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1844838/242) in the first dupe (where [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/17809/242) proves it via BT=Binomial Theorem), or directly invoke BT as in the 2nd dupe.  Much easier, use the Congruence Power Rule [as here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/17800/242) in the 1st dupe.

Answer (score 2):

$$7^n + 2 = (6+1)^n + 2$$
Apply the binomial theorem to evaluate the first term on the RHS

$$\left(\sum_\limits{k=0}^n {n\choose k} 6^{k}1^{n-k}\right) + 2$$

In that summation every term where $k > 0$ we see that  $3|6^{k}$ and hence $3\Bigg|\displaystyle{n\choose k} 6^{k}1^{n-k}$

When $k = 0$ we have $\displaystyle{n\choose 0} 6^{0}1^{n} = 1$

And $3|1+2$

Comment: I proposed a duplicate but there are plenty others: may be you could propose a better one (instead of this answer).

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: @BillDubuque this question was not marked as dupe when I answered it.  However, I did not search the database for similar questions before I posted my answer.

Comment: Surely you have enough experience by now to know questions like this have been answered *many* times already. If you are unable help organize the site then please refrain from answering such dupes (cf. linked site policy).