# Show that $(x^{2^k}+1)\mid (x^{2^l}-1)$, when $k<l$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I found this in some notes from a course in number theory. How do i work to solve this?

Comment: Write $x^{2^k}=y$. Can you show that $y+1\mid y^2-1\mid y^{2^{\ell-k}}-1$?

Comment: Meaning that the question is reduced to this [near duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1119429/11619).

Comment: Also, I highly recommend that you take a look at [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619). The question is a bit lacking in the context department. If you could convince us that you are not just trying to get somebody to do your homework we would feel a lot better about the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$x^{2^l}-1=(x^{2^{l-1}}+1)(x^{2^{l-1}}-1)$$
Continue to expand the right hand factor until you get 
$$x^{2^l}-1=(x-1)\prod_{k=0}^{l-1} \left(x^{2^k}+1\right)$$
Which is obviously divisible by $x^{2^k}+1$ for all $0\le k\lt l$.

Answer (score 1):

$\bmod\, x^{\large 2^{\Large K}}\!\!+1\!:\ \ \color{#c00}{x^{\large 2^{\Large K}}\!\!\equiv -1}\,\Rightarrow\, x^{\large 2^{\Large K+N}}\!\!\equiv (\color{#c00}{x^{\large 2^{\Large K}}})^{\large 2^{\Large N}}\!\!\equiv (\color{#c00}{-1})^{\large 2^{\Large N}}\!\!\equiv 1\ $ $\!\!\overbrace{{\rm when} \ \ N> 0}^{\large K\, <\, K+N\, =:\, L_{\phantom{I_I}}}$

---

**Remark** $ $ It's a special case of $\ x^{\large K}\!+1\mid x^{\large 2K}\!-1\mid x^{\large 2KN}\!-1,\,$ also provable  by mod

$\bmod\, x^{\large K}\!+1\!:\ \ \color{#c00}{x^{\large K}
\!\!\equiv -1}\,\Rightarrow\, x^{\large 2KN}
\!\equiv (\color{#c00}{x^{\large K}})^{\large 2N}\!\equiv (\color{#c00}{-1})^{\large 2N}\!\equiv 1\ $

Comment: If you learn to reason by $\!\bmod$ as above then you don't have to remember motley divisibility formulas - they occur very naturally as special cases of general results (e.g. abobe that $\,(-1)^{2N} = 1)\ \ $